# gtk treeview column resizing and horizontal scrollbar

Tags: gtk

I have a gtk treeview (inside a GtkScrolledWindow) with two columns.

If I set both columns to the default sizing policy, I have a horizontal scrollbar for the treeview but the columns can't be sized down by the user, which is impractical.

If I set both columns to setSizing Fixed, fixed width 120, I get a nice display and the columns can be resized, but there is no horizontal scrollbar in the treeview (since the columns size down to fit in the width of the treeview I guess).

If I set the first column to setSizing fixed, fixed width 120, the second one to automatic, only the second column is displayed (???).

I would like that by default the first column takes let's say at most 60% of the display, the second column can go all the way and I have a horizontal scrollbar. Certainly I want the user to be able to resize them up or down, not as with the default policy, that you can resize them down!
That's why I tried the first column fixed, the second automatic, it was promessing but I don't understand why the first column is not displayed at all in that configuration.

I add the cell renderers with packstart true, I tried false but it didn't change anything, also I tried setting the expand for the columns to true or false, which didn't have any effect.

Note I'm using the gtk2hs haskell bindings but I'm certain it would be the same in any other gtk binding. Just mentioning if people will ask for code samples.

I'm pretty sure this is a common problem... I'd say nautilus is fixing it the way I'd like to fix it, but I think digging in the nautilus source is going to be quite long...

**EDIT** well i've discovered the cell renderer's ellipsize setting also has an effect. Setting it to end for the first column and none for the second should be what i want but then the first column is very small and cannot be expanded through resize...

**EDIT2** well for now i've moved to word wrapping for the cell renderer, that way i don't have to bother with a horizontal scrollbar... Still curious for the solution to that question though.